# How to properly establish a one-to-many relationship and ensure the effective functionality of the orderBy operation?

Tags: sql, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I encountered challenges while dealing with relationships in PostgreSQL.

My stack:
`Nestjs, typeorm, postgres.`

I possess two entities: "category" and "categoryTranslation." It's evident that "categoryTranslation" serves the purpose of storing category translations, constituting a crucial element of the multi-language functionality. These entities are designed with simplicity in mind.

```
@Entity({ name: 'category' })
export class CategoryEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column('varchar')
  name: string;

  @Column('varchar')
  description: string;

  @OneToMany(
    _type => CategoryTranslationEntity,
    categoryTranslation => categoryTranslation.category,
  )
  categoryTranslation: CategoryTranslationEntity[];
}

@Entity({ name: 'category_translation' })
export class CategoryTranslationEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column('varchar')
  name: string;

  @Column('varchar')
  description: string;

  @Column('integer', { name: 'language_id' })
  languageId: number;

  @Column('integer', { name: 'category_id' })
  categoryId: number;

  @ManyToOne(_type => CategoryEntity, category => category.id, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'category_id' })
  category: CategoryEntity;
}
```

As evident from the structure, the "categoryTranslation" entity mirrors the fields of the "category" entity that are subject to translation. Moreover, it includes the languageId and categoryId as additional attributes, with categoryId serving as a reference.

My intention was to initiate a frontend request to retrieve a list of categories. I send a languageId as a header parameter, subsequently performing an innerJoin and select operation with a condition (which I acknowledge may not be completely accurate). Following this, I obtain the data in the ensuing format:

```
CategoryEntity {
        id: 65,
        name: 'Pumpkin pie',
        description: 'Description for Pumpkin pie',
        categoryTranslation: [ [CategoryTranslationEntity] ]
      },
      CategoryEntity {
        id: 72,
        name: 'Pickles',
        description: 'Description for Pickles',
        categoryTranslation: [ [CategoryTranslationEntity] ]
      }
```

Prior to sending the data back to the frontend, I employ a map function that substitutes the name and description attributes from the "categoryEntity" with those from the "categoryTranslationEntity" object. In cases where the "categoryTranslation" lacks the required translation or remains empty, I retain the English translation as a fallback.

The present challenge I'm encountering revolves around complications with the orderBy and textFilter functionalities. From my understanding, using innerJoin and selecting with a third argument as a condition might lead to unexpected behavior, which seems to be the case in my situation. Given this context and insight into the overall scenario and codebase, could you provide recommendations for more effective strategies to manage my translation entities?